# Call AccountKit API from C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to call AccountKit dialog from C++ but there's no doccumentation about it's builder signature

```
QAndroidIntent intent(QtAndroid::androidActivity().object(), 
                    "com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity");

QAndroidJniObject configurationBuilder("com/facebook/accountkit/ui/AccountKitConfiguration$AccountKitConfigurationBuilder",
                                       "(Lcom/facebook/accountkit/ui/LoginType;Lcom/facebook/accountkit/ui/AccountKitActivity/ResponseType;)V",
                                       0, 0);
```

I'd like to know the types and perhaps know where FB has detailed API docs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the signatures with `javap` just to later find the reference docs, so I've just created an wrapper that allows one to completely avoid the java code:
https://github.com/ceciletti/third-party-qt-utils/tree/master/com_facebook_AccountKit

Hope one find this useful